# If theme has a built-in SEO, can I still use Yoast SEO plugin?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, seo, yoast

I want to switch theme on Wordpress based online magazine.

Right now, Voux theme is used and SEO is done with Yoast SEO plugin. However, the new theme (DI Magazine) that I would like to make a switch to, has a built-in SEO if I understood their documentation correctly.

So, can I continue using Yoast SEO or will there be any conflict because of the theme's built-in SEO? 
Also, if I can continue using Yoast SEO, changing the theme won't affect current settings made in a plugin, right?

Comment: ^ OP isn't looking for help with keywords or asking how to rank higher, it looks like they just want to know if a plugin is compatible with their theme. They will need to contact the dev who created the theme to answer this question. Changing the theme will not affect OPs Yoast settings for pages, posts, and general settings but custom post type information settings might have to be revisited.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to address this question to your theme's developer team, because they will know best, if their theme code is compatible with Yoast SEO or if there will be any issues when running Yoast SEO alongside.

To contact your new theme's developer, try posting your question in the official WordPress.org support forum of DI Magazine Theme:
https://wordpress.org/support/theme/di-magazine/

Best of luck
Saskia